# PDF Report within Cucumber

Tags: ruby, pdf, cucumber

I'm trying to get a PDF report to output once all of my scenarios are complete in Cucumber.

I've seen online that there is a gem "Prawn" that will allow this.

When typing my command line:

```
cucumber -f pretty -f pdf --out C:\filename
```

I'm getting the following message:

```
cannot load such file -- pdf
Error creating formatter: pdf (LoadError)
```

The gems i've got are Prawn, Prawn Core, Prawn Layout and Prawn Security.

What am I missing to make this work?

thank you

Comment: The exception says that Cucumber cannot find the PDF report formatter. I do not believe there is a built-in formatter for PDF, so you would need to setup a [custom formatter](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters).

Comment: The article I read suggested you only needed the gems. I get the feeling they were lying!